# Return data on HTTP upload to sanic server

Tags: python, http, file-upload, sanic

I'm experimenting with uploading data to a `sanic` web server. To do so I issue a POST request using curl. I try to return some data after the POST request. The rationale behind this is to return some ID now representing the upload on the server side. But this doesn't seem to work. Now I'm wondering: Is my program wrong? Does `curl` not write the output? Or is this a bug in `sanic`? Could anyone help me here? Thanks!

Here's the Python program:

```
import signal
import asyncio
import uvloop

import sanic

app = sanic.Sanic(__name__)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
server = app.create_server(host="localhost", port=3002)
task = asyncio.ensure_future(server)

@app.post("/testUpload", stream=True)
async def api_testUpload(request):

    async def doStream(response):
        while True:
            body = await request.stream.get()
            if body is None:
                break

            sanic.response.json({
                "result": "good!"
            })

    return sanic.response.stream(doStream)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda s, f: loop.stop())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except:
    loop.stop()
```

You can invoke `curl` like this:

```
curl -v --data-binary "@somefile.data" http://localhost:3002/testUpload
```

And here is what `curl` writes to STDOUT:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3002 (#0)
> POST /testUpload HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3002
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 334504
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Keep-Alive: 5
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

As you can see, a `text/plain` response is generated. This should be an `application/json` with my data, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to do it. The `sanic` API does not work that intuitively here. In order to write data after receiving the bytes sent you have to do it this way within the streaming function `doStream()`:

```
await response.write(json.dumps({
    "result": "good!"
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you do not need to stream at all. It seems to me like what you are attempting to do is:

- upload a file
- process the file and do something
- return a response to say that something was done

Assuming this is the case, then you do not need to stream at all.

```
import sanic

app = sanic.Sanic(__name__)

def do_something(file):
    print(f'doing something to {file.name}')

@app.post("/testUpload")
async def api_testUpload(request):
    myfile = request.files.get('myfile')

    do_something(myfile)

    return sanic.response.json({
        'body': myfile.body,
        'name': myfile.name,
        'type': myfile.type,
    })

app.run(host='localhost', port=3002, auto_reload=True)
```

You can then hit your endpoint with a file ...

```
curl -i -F "myfile=@/tmp/somefile.txt" http://localhost:3002/testUpload
```

And you should see in your logs:

```
[2018-10-25 10:09:56 +0300] [16051] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://localhost:3002
[2018-10-25 10:09:56 +0300] [16055] [INFO] Starting worker [16055]
doing something to somefile.txt
[2018-10-25 10:09:59 +0300] - (sanic.access)[INFO][127.0.0.1:39306]: POST http://localhost:3002/testUpload  200 62
```

And your return

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: 5
Content-Length: 62
Content-Type: application/json

{"body":"FOOBAR\n","name":"somefile.txt","type":"text\/plain"}
```

Now, I suppose if you are uploading a file, and you wanted to stream the response of that upload as it was happening to that request or another, that would be a different issue.

I hope this helps.